# Selectively loading elements from jld file in Julia

Tags: tuples, julia, loading

I saved an object named `results` in Julia with the `JLD`package writing

`@save "res.jld" results`

The object `results`is a

`81-element Array{Tuple{Int64,Float64,Array{Array{Array{Int64,1},1},1},Array{Array{Array{Int64,1},1},1},Array{Int64,1}},1}`

where each element has 5 elements: `Int64`, `Float64`, `Array{Array{Array{Int64,1},1},1}`, `Array{Array{Array{Int64,1},1},1}` and `Array{Int64,1}`.

How can I have access to the first 2 elements of each element (the `Int64`and the `Float64`) without loading the whole file, because it requires a large amount of memory. I want to avoid `@load "res.jld"`because it's too heavy.

Comment: JLD is deprecated, you should use JLD2 instead. Also, I don't think you can do what you request here with the functions in the package.

Comment: JLD2 also seems abandoned. See discussion here: https://discourse.julialang.org/t/cant-read-old-jld2-file/20708/5

Comment: Oh.... wasn't aware of that .... I have a lot of files stored in the JLD format... :-( I must then forget about my files and throw them away ? Can't do that .... What's the best way to save objects in Julia , then? Thank you for your comments !

Comment: Reasonable and stable options include: in-built Julia serialization (`serialize()`) for short term storage and `BSON.jl` for long term storage. Yet you need a columnar data format - have a look at `Parquet.jl`

Comment: Wonderful ! Thank you a lot !

Comment: Stefan Karpinski just wrote on Slack that JLD2 is definitely not abandoned.

Comment: Yes I saw it too ! Would be nice if there is a way to convert all my JLD files to JLD2 files ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are looking for isn't quite possible I'm afraid. There is [hyperslabbing](https://www.asc.ohio-state.edu/wilkins.5/computing/HDF/hdf5tutorial/select.html) and it is also [partially supported](https://github.com/JuliaIO/JLD.jl/blob/master/src/JLD.jl#L738) by JLD (simple example [here](https://github.com/JuliaIO/JLD.jl/issues/239)). It will allow you to read in each element one by one. However, it doesn't enable you to only load only the first two components of each element.

Nonetheless, iterating over each element one by one might be still useful as you can avoid loading the full dataset into memory (hence you could process a dataset that is too large to be kept in memory). It probably isn't faster than loading the full dataset (if you can) though.

Creating some (simplified) fake data and saving it to disk

```
using JLD
results = [(i, Float64(i), rand(3)) for i in 1:1000];
@save "res.jld" results
```

Basically, what I was describing above would look like this

```
jldopen("res.jld") do f
    for k in 1:length(f["results"])
        f["results"][k][1][1:2] # read k-th element and extract first two components.
    end
end
```

Comment: Thank you for your help ! That's a big help even if what I'm looking for is difficult :-) thank you !

Comment: Glad that I could be of help!

Comment: I tried your suggestion and was super quick to read the elements :-) But where are the results stored? In f? Or somewhere else?